# Django admin view uploaded photo

Tags: django, file-upload, django-admin, imageview

I have implemented photo upload in Django but I have a problem to view it Django admin.

**models.py**

```
class WorkPlacePhoto(models.Model):

    file = models.FileField(storage=FileSystemStorage(location=settings.MEDIA_ROOT), upload_to='uploads')
```

Photos are saved in `PATH_TO_APP/media/uploads/` and I can view them in my app. However, in admin panel, when I clicked on the link which admin app is generated it gives me 404 error as

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1/admin/wpphotos/workplacephoto/9/media/uploads/aosa_glb_ho_778_hi.jpg/

u'9/media/uploads/aosa_glb_ho_778_hi.jpg' object is not found
```

Although the message is clear, I couldn't figure out which url should be written to view the image and of course how admin class should be modified.

I glad to suggest me a way to achieve this. Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From you description I am guessing your [MEDIA_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#media-url) isn't set correctly, something which is a bit tricky to do using the Django development web server.

I am guessing that the link's href would probably be `media/uploads/aosa_glb_ho_778_hi.jpg` where you probably want `/media/uploads/aosa_glb_ho_778_hi.jpg` so it is relative to `http://127.0.0.1/` not to where you happen to be now `http://127.0.0.1/admin/wpphotos/workplacephoto/9/`.

See the [static files documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development) for inspiration of how to serve your images with the Django development server.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but I managed to fix it -but it's not a correct method and I'd like to use a better solution if possible.
What I did was, I have apache running on port 80, so I created a symbolic link in the `/var/www` folder which is pointing to the `Images` folder in my Django App directory. And the Media URL is basically this:

```
MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1/Images/'
```

This work fine, but I don't like the solution.
I didn't quite follow the solution explained above. Could someone please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have in your settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

Being the url relative, you have that behavior in the admin panel. The solution would be to set the url as absolute

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 0):

By now, you probably either solved your problem or quit it altogether, but after all these years people (like me) still have this problem. Here's how I just solved it:

1. On settings.py, I set not only `STATIC_URL` (with the name of the static folder) and `STATIC_URL` (with the path to that folder) but I also set `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` accordingly, where the uploaded images will be stored at;
2. On my model class, I have my picture field looking as follow:

   ```
   picture = models.FileField(upload_to='images/')
   ```

It will upload the image to my MEDIA_ROOT folder, appending `/images/` to it.

3. And finally, on my urls.py, my urlpatterns looks like this:

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
   ```

Notice how I appended the static right after the list.

Django's documentation makes it clear that this strategy is not recommended for production environment and it gives some alternatives you can choose from. For more information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development