# Django Admin won't find uploaded files

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django 3.0 Model with a FileField:

```
# models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    photo = models.FileField(
        upload_to='photos/',
        help_text='Select photo to upload'
    )
```

My `settings.py` file defines `MEDIA_ROOT` in terms of `BASE_DIR` as

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myApp/static/myApp/')
```

and I've confirmed that

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ~me/ProjectRoot/myProject/myApp/static/myApp/
```

exactly as I intend.

When I upload a photo file through the Profile Admin "add" page, that photo appears in the folder `~me/ProjectRoot/myProject/myApp/static/myApp/photos/` exactly as intended.  When I revisit that Profile's Admin "change" page, the upload widget displays as

```
Currently: photos/uploaded_photo.png     [ ] clear
Change: [Browse]   No file selected.
```

showing a link that's ostensibly to the file I've already uploaded.  The link itself is to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/myApp/profiles/9/change/photos/uploaded_photo.png
```

(here, '9' is the primary key `id` of the Profile in question in the database).

When I select the link, instead of viewing the uploaded photo, the Admin home page loads with a warning banner at the top that says
"Profile with ID “9/change/photos/uploaded_photo.png” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted?"

If I go to the database itself, I can clearly see that the Profile exists there:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM myApp_profile;

+----+----------------------------------+
| id | photo                            |
+----+----------------------------------+
...
| 9  | photos/uploaded_photo.png        |
```

I also double-checked the upload folder, and the file `myApp/static/myApp/photos/uploaded_photo.png` is still there, undeleted.

I've read the following Documentation pages, which did not address this issue:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/

I've also found this Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670021/django-admin-view-uploaded-photo).  All of its answers involve `MEDIA_ROOT` not being set correctly, which I don't believe is my problem.

What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: How do you normally access your static files? Can you share your project `urls.py`?

Comment: @BernardoDuarte I normally access static files using `{% load static %}` and `{% static 'myApp/filepath/file.ext' %}` in the template.  My `urls.py` contains only `url_patterns` with `path('admin/', admin.site.urls),` plus URL config for non-admin views that aren't related to the problem.

Comment: Can you have a look at [this docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/) I believe that will help you, however I'm not sure whats causing your problem.

Comment: @BernardoDuarte Thanks, but I'm already using static files successfully everywhere else in the app.  This is a problem specifically with the Admin, and there's nothing in that link that applies

Comment: I find [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18632566/7395911) very similar, can you have a look?

Comment: Thanks for another lead.  Unfortunately, the only good answer there is out-of-date and just doesn't work with Django 3 (url() in `urls.py` no longer exists, for example).  Since the poster there doesn't explain what they're doing, I can't adapt it to Django 3.

Comment: you need to add photos folder in Media_root 'myApp/static/myApp/photos' causer the location shows that the image is inside photo folder